# How can i get a file name inside a iteration loop?

Tags: python, shutil

I wanted to implement the following python programm. I want it to compare files and if there's no correspondence copy it in another folder.

This is what I did:

```
import os, sys
import shutil
from pathlib import Path


images_backup = [f for f in os.listdir(r"D:\test\backup")]
sorted_c = [f for f in os.listdir(r"D:\test\sort\c")]
sorted_me = [f for f in os.listdir(r"D:\test\sort\me")]
sorted_m = [f for f in os.listdir(r"D:\test\sort\m")]

flag=[0,0,0]

for image in images_backup:
    flag_list=[0,0,0]
    for im in sorted_c:
        if Path(r'D:\test\backup\image').stem==Path(r'D:\test\backup\sort\c\im').stem:
         break
        flag[0]=1
    for im in sorted_me:
        if Path(r'D:\test\backup\image').stem==Path(r'D:\test\backup\sort\me\im').stem:
         break
        flag[1]=1
    for im in sorted_m:
        if Path(r'D:\test\backup\image').stem==Path(r'D:\test\backup\sort\m\im').stem:
         break
        flag[2]=1
    if flag==[1,1,1]:
        new_path = r'D:\test\stash'
        shutil.move(r"D:\test\backup"+'\image', new_path)
```

As you can see I have the folder 'backup' on which I iterate with the outer loop, then I have for each file of the folder 'backup' 3 loops, one for each folder I want to compare.
The problem I encounter is when i want to compare the file names in:

`Path(r'D:\test\backup\image').stem==Path(r'D:\test\backup\sort\c\im').stem`

Path(r'D:\test\backup\image').stem returns "image" which is correctly the name assigned by the loop for, but I want the name of the original file in the 'backup' folder. What can i do to get it and then compare it?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to do `rf"D:\test\backup\{image}"` instead? Your current code uses a hardcoded string rather than replacing it with the variables. I'd also like to point out that you are setting your flags to `1` outside of the if statement, so it will always be set to `1` unless the first if statement in the loop returns True.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `for image in images_backup:`, what do you think this means? What do you expect will be the value of `image` each time through the loop? Do you see how this can be used to solve the problem? Or do you have a more specific question?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the intent of your code correctly, which is that you want to move the image from `backup` to `stash` if it's not in any of the three other folders, you can simplify it down a lot by getting all the filenames (or rather, just their stems, since that's what you want to compare against) from the three folders and putting them in a single set that you can use for testing each of the `backup` images.

```
import os
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

backup_path = r"D:\test\backup"
stash_path = r'D:\test\stash'
other_paths = (
    r"D:\test\sort\c",
    r"D:\test\sort\me",
    r"D:\test\sort\m",
)

backup_images = os.listdir(backup_path)
other_stems = {
    Path(f).stem
    for path in other_paths
    for f in os.listdir(path)
}

for image in backup_images:
    if Path(image).stem not in other_stems:
        shutil.move(
            os.path.join(backup_path, image),
            stash_path
        )
```

Comment: INFINITELY THANKS! I finally can reorder my files without effort, I definitely needed your help, my code was too much convoluted and I didnt know that a function useful like 'in' existed. So glad u helped!